# JDK 7 and Android IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, compatibility, java-7

I have  jdk 6 and 7 installed on my PC.

On this link https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#ExistingIDE , I read that Android IDE is compatible with jdk 6, but I want to know if Android SDK works also with jdk 7 or if there are problems ?

If there are problems can I mantain the jdk 7 and configure Android sdk to use Jdk 6 ?

Comment: `can I mantain the jdk 7 and configure ANdroid sdk to use Jdk 6?` **Yes**.

Comment: If you're planning to use JDK 7 and some of its new features in your app, then you may want to have a read of this [post](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1966024).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Java 1.7 for the android development.

Starting from build tools 19, Android has full support for Java 1.7. So you can set 1.7 as source and target for compilation. Support for this is from Android studio 0.3.2. Android kitkat has full support of JAVA 1.7 API, but most of language features from 1.7, can be used on the older android versions too.

Edit:
You can also mantain the jdk 7 and configure the Android application to use Jdk 6 during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a project using JDK 7 in Eclipse with the ADT plugin with no extra configuration and with any version of the ADT plugin, so long as you only use features in JDK 6.

Support for Java 7 language features was added to the Eclipse ADT plugin in March 2014 (ADT 22.6.0 and up). All you need to do is update your application project settings to use JDK 7 and ensure that Eclipse is running on JDK 7 as well.

Note that unless your `minSdkVersion` is 19+ (KitKat), you cannot use try-with-resources.

From the [ADT plugin tools page](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html):

> ADT 22.6.0 (March 2014)
>
> General Notes:
>
> - Added support for Java 7 language features like multi-catch, try-with-resources, and the diamond operator. These features require
>     version 19 or higher of the Build Tools. Try-with-resources requires
>     minSdkVersion 19; the rest of the new language features require
>     minSdkVersion 8 or higher.
>
>   To use the new language features after
>     installing ADT 22.6.0, ensure that you run Eclipse on JDK 7 and change
>     your application project settings to use JDK 7.

Answer (score 0):

It's not even necessary to have JDK 6 installed. You can just configure Eclipse to "compile as JDK 6" and it will work.

To change for the whole workspace, enter *Window* -> *Preferences*, then *Java* -> *Compiler* and set *Compiler compliance level* to 1.6.

You can also do this in individual projects, if you prefer, in *Project* -> *Properties* -> *Java Compiler*.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem today http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html where the recommended jdk is 1.6 but according to the main bundle Android has full support for 1.7 http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio.

So I woudl say...Yes! 8 )